# ddrescue to larger drive

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a 2tb external hard drive with a ext3 filesystem on the entire drive, so no partitions. I suppose this means there is also no partition table? This drive is somewhat broken, as copying some files results in i/o errors.

Therefore I decided to clone the disk using ddrescue, using the following commands:

```
ddrescue -f -n /dev/sdc /dev/sdd recovery.log
ddrescue -f -r 3 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd recovery.log
```

The latter displayed the following output:

```
Retrying bad sectors... Retry 3 (forwards)
ipos:    1985 GB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
opos:    1985 GB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       8 B/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:    28672 B,    error rate:     128 B/s
rescued:    2000 GB,   bad areas:        5,        run time:     16m 27s
pct rescued:   99.99%, read errors:      261,  remaining time:         n/a
                          time since last successful read:      1m 56s
```

The destination disk (/dev/sdd) is a 4tb disk which I did not do anything with after getting it from the store. Now that ddrescue has finished the new disk shows a 258gb partition and 3.41tb unused space...

Trying to read more about this I am wondering if the problem could be that there is a GPT header in the end of the new disk which is not from the original disk (/dev/sdc), but I'm not sure how to check this or how to fix it. Or if the problem is that there was no partition at all on the original disk, now that I think of it, I don't even know what I would expect actually.

Anyway, I'm not sure how to proceed. I suppose the data is there on the new disk, but is there any way to access it? How would I do that?

Comment: You should be able to mount it the same way you mounted it before? Do you want  a partition table or not? (Could've ddrescue'd to a partition directly, but no sense in trying to ddrescue a misbehaving drive twice, as it might fail).

Comment: "Now that ddrescue has finished the new disk shows a 258gb partition..." What tool is showing you this partition? Given there was no partition to begin with, I don't see how a partition table would have been created by `ddrescue`.